# CA1506 code analysis issue on VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I got [CA1506](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397994.aspx) issue. It appears only in VS 2012 Ultimate. When I open solution in VS2010 Premium and run code analysis everything is OK.

Does anybody know what is the reason of that behavior and what should I do to have the same behavior on both environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[CodeGenerated]` attribute for a number of elements has [changed from the type level to the method level](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/11/net-framework-sdk-45-changes-visual.html). This will cause these types to now be evaluated by Code Analysis, where they were previously ignored.

Plus, a number of fixes were applied to the FxCop engine (which is the underlying engine for Code Analysis and Code Metrics), which improved the accuracy of the rules. Some rules therefore now trigger when they really should, or no longer trigger when they originally shouldn't have.

Given that Visual Studio 2010 will use the 10.0 version of the rules and of the engine, and that 2012 will use the 11.0 version of the rules and the engine, you'll find that the only real way to get the behavior you want is to either exclusively use 2010 or 2012.

Whichever you decide, the items reported by Visual Studio 2012 are very likely to be actual issues you'll want to investigate and fix, regardless of whether 2010 finds and reports them.